# Terraform enable aws vpc_flow_logs for existing vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc

I'm using terraform to run some checks on my AWS environment.
I would like to check if there are any existing VPCs (I don't know if they exist), and if they exist, I need to set tags and allow `vpc_flow_logs`.

I'm trying using this code, but I can't receive info on the VPC.

```
locals {
  flow_logs_to_cw_logs = var.enable_flow_logs && var.flow_logs_destination_type == "cloud-watch-logs"
}

output "aws_vpc" {
  description = "The VPC."
  value       = aws_vpc.my_vpc
}

data "aws_vpcs" "my_vpcs" {
  tags = merge(
    var.tags
  )
}

data "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
  count = length(data.aws_vpcs.my_vpcs.ids)
  id    = tolist(data.aws_vpcs.my_vpcs.ids)[count.index]
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "vpc_flow_logs" {
  count = var.enable_flow_logs && local.flow_logs_to_cw_logs ? 1 : 0

  name              = var.flow_logs_log_group_name
  retention_in_days = var.flow_logs_retention_in_days

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "aws_flow_log" "vpc_flow_logs" {
  count = var.enable_flow_logs ? 1 : 0

  log_destination_type  = var.flow_logs_destination_type
  log_destination       = local.flow_logs_to_cw_logs ? aws_cloudwatch_log_group.vpc_flow_logs[0].arn : "${var.flow_logs_s3_arn}/${var.flow_logs_s3_key_prefix}"
  iam_role_arn          = local.flow_logs_to_cw_logs ? var.flow_logs_iam_role_arn : null
  count_vpc_id          = length(data.aws_vpcs.my_vpcs.ids)
  vpc_id                = data.aws_vpc.my_vpc[count_vpc_id.index].id

  traffic_type          = "ALL"

  tags = var.tags
}
```

Comment: Honestly I would write a script to do this kind of stuff

Comment: Hi @Paolo thanks for the reply.  
Is there an example?

Comment: You mentioned, "I'm trying using this code, but I can't receive info on the vpc." Could you put the actual error or output you receive when you try to apply this?

Comment: Not possible via `aws_vpc` data source as it doesn't expose that information. You will have to extract that info separately and then iterate over the desired VPC list to create the `aws_flow_log` resource for them.